# how to regexp_extract between delimiter nth on hive with talend

Tags: regex, hiveql

so I have been working to separate random text with ^ delimiter

Note: I dont use `split`, because its limit due my talend. so `regexp_extract` only.

The text looks like this:

```
1^^^prophalena^BB^^^^^^^^^VVRT^4^206_MEE65^098740^0206_09^0ID00980990^1
^^^alchemist^^^^^^^^^^^8^314_YOUR^094589740^099_PPPP^0PP746739200^1
```

I already tried those regex to extract `prophalena` in various cases:

1. resulting `mapredtask2`

```
select regexp_extract(value,'^(?:[^\\^]*\^){3}([^\\^]*',1)
```

2. resulting 0 value

```
select regexp_extract(value, '^(?:([^^]+)\^?){4}',1)
```

what went wrong here? what should I do ?

Comment: The first pattern is missing the final `)`. Try ``regexp_extract(value, '^(?:[^^]*\^){3}([^^]*)', 1)`` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/nRbtvn/1)). Note there is no `mapredtask2` inside either of the strings you provided.

Comment: hey, thanks! how about if I want to extract the VVRT? or the other? I already try to change number in brackets {3} to {14} but it doesnt work.

Comment: Since it is the 14th field, use `13`, `^(?:[^^]*\^){13}([^^]*)`.

Comment: unfortunately, the regex doesnt work when I set the bracket to more then 1. It results like the {1}

Answer (score 0):

The first pattern is missing the final `)` and you added unnecessary backslashes in the character classes.

You can use

```
regexp_extract(value, '^(?:[^^]*\^){3}([^^]*)', 1)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nRbtvn/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[^^]*\^){3}` - three occurrences of any chars other than `^` and then a `^` char
- `([^^]*)` - the **fourth** field, zero or more chars other than `^`.

So, the number inside the curly braces is the N-1 value (if you need the 14th field, use `{13}`).